# How to Add N before sp parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have the bellow sp in sql:

```
     create proc spGetValue(@Field nvarchar(20))
     as
     select * from ASI_TblWorkflow
     where Caption = @Field
```

when i call sp like this : exec spGetValue @Field = 'مرحله'
it does not return any record. but if i use N before my string like N'مرحله' it returns required records. 
i know that n is for National language character, but since my parameter is Nvarchar, why do i need N before my value? 
in addition i call this sp from my c# code. and i can not add N before my string values. how can i add N before my parameter inside sp?!

Comment: `'this'` is a varchar, whist `N'this'` is nvarchar.  When you assign a varchar field to an nvarchar it is implicitly cast; which most of the time is fine.  However when you're making use of unicode features the varchar will not be able to hold those values, so this information is lost even before it's converted to nvarchar.  Unfortunately there's no way for the system to be inelligent in figuring out that the varchar you assigned to initially should have been an nvarchar; you have to tell it.

Comment: `N` declares the string as `NVARCHAR`, Can you not map the parameter from c# to `SqlDbType.NVarChar`?

Comment: my parameter is string. i could not find any way to convert string to SqlDbType.NVarChar. i have some other sp with nvarchar parameter and the same Persian values that works fine!

Comment: You may not need the N when you call it from C#. Strings in C# are always Unicode, so should map to nvarchar with no problems.

Comment: i used to think like this. but now i see that it does not work. as u see my sp parameter is nvarchar and my variable in c# is string too. i wonder why it does not work!

Comment: You haven't shown your C# code. Maybe it's something simpler than this. It's not the string/nvarchar issue, because, in general, there is no string/nvarchar issue.

Comment: .NET string supports Unicode and will take care of it automatically (N' will be prepended automatically.) There should be some problems in your code.

Comment: here is my c# code : public WorkflowInfo GetManualNextflow(int FormID, string FieldName, string Value)
        {
            using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
            {
                var item = ctx.ExecuteSingleOrDefault<WorkflowInfo>(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, PublicValues.spBPMGetManualNextflow, FormID, FieldName, Value);
                return item;
            }
        }

Comment: and here is how i call it :  string val = txtConditionValue.Text;

                var cntWorkflow = new WorkflowController();                
                var nextworkflow = cntWorkflow.GetManualNextflow(ItemId, drpConditionField.SelectedValue, val);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("spGetValue", connection);
sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter pField = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Field", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
pField.Value = "value here";

connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Microsoft does it differently: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx  SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(
        "@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16);
    param.Value = "Beverages";
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

Comment: did not work, it will adds N before string which looses some chars in string

Answer (score -4):

```
CREATE TABLE tblIPBlackList (IPAddress varchar(50))
go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddIPToBlacklist]
 @ipAddress nvarchar(50) = ''
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 INSERT INTO [tblIPBlackList] ([IPAddress]) VALUES (@ipAddress)
 END

 go
 exec AddIPToBlacklist @ipAddress=N'127.0.0.1'

 select * from tblIPBlackList
```